# Eigenvalues of the adjoint representation of a matrix with distinct eigenvalues

Tags: lie-algebras

This is question 1.6 from Humphrey's "Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory":

> Suppose $x \in \mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathrm{F})$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues $a_1,\ldots,a_n$. The eigenvalues of the adjoint representation $\mathrm{ad}(x)$ are then precisely the $n^2$ scalars $a_i - a_j$ for $1\leq i,j \leq n$, which of course need not to be distinct.

How do I go on proving this? Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Thank you! When I searched for it, I couldn't find the duplicate unfortunately...

Comment: No problem, sometimes questions are hard to find on the site but once you ask it, the question pops out in the "Related" section on the right side (that's where I saw it).